# How to handle the model passing through appended Underscore template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, marionette

I know it is easy to handle the model when the model and template are separated. 
But when I append a template in a view and pass a model to it, I want to trigger a event to destroy the model which I passed.  Here is part of codes:

```
ImageView.extends Marionette.ItemView
events:
  'click [data-event=delete]' : 'delete'

ui:
  'image' : 'div[name=image]'

template : """
  <img src='<%=image.get('url')%>' />
  <a data-event=delete>X</a>
"""
addImage : (image) ->
  @ui.image.append _.template(@template)({ image: image })

delete : ->    //I can trigger this event, but no idea how to pass the image model in order to
               //delete it
  upload.destory()
```

The image shows properly, which means the template received the model, but how do I pass the image model in the triggered event?

Comment: Don't know Marionette but in plain Backbone, your `image` would be the view's `this.model` in a single item view. Then you wouldn't have `addImage` at all, you'd just say `new ImageView(model: image)`. If your `ImageView` is actually viewing several images then you should have a collection view for the whole list and separate image views for each image.

Comment: @muistooshort right, you could access model using `this.model` in `Marionette.ItemView`. But the callback you are using is wrong. You should use `onRender` in this case and destroy model there. Besides, `model.destroy()` will trigger `destroy` event that could destroy your `ImageView`, maybe `this.model.destroy({silent:true})` will help.

Comment: @VahanVardanyan I don't know Marionette, I'm just making some guesses based on plain Backbone and [Derick Bailey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/93448/derick-bailey)'s good sense. Maybe you could flesh out that comment a bit and turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Marionette.ItemView's callback methods](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#events-and-callback-methods) which will help you to destroy `Image model`.

ItemView's `onRender` callback will be the right choice.

```
var ImageView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   // you initialization, ui bindings, etc
   onBeforeRender: function () {
       // Triggered before an ItemView is rendered.
   },
   // Here you can destroy your model
   onRender: function () {
       // Triggered after the view has been rendered.
       this.model.destroy();
   }
});
```

`onRender` will be called after the view has been rendered and `this.model.destroy()` will destroy the model associated with the current `ItemView`.